# Como tornar um projeto de público para privado no GitHub?

Tags: github

Tenho um projeto público na conta gratuita, tem como torná-lo privado?

Comment: Achei a pergunta suficientemente aceitável para a comunidade, não vi justificativas para a pergunta ter 4 votos negativos. Alguém que votou poderia justificar?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a pergunta não é sobre programação, não é um erro e não caracteriza uma dúvida sobre programação. Posso ter me equivocado, mas no meu entendimento, não pertence ao site. Caso esteja errado, me avise que eu modifico o voto.

Comment: @HiagoSouza Mas é sobre repositórios e GitHub, ferramentas cotidianas para o desenvolvedor previstas no [4º item desta lista](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/5878).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você tem razão! Desculpem o equivoco, vou modificar o voto para positivo.

Answer (score 12):

> Basta ir às configurações do seu repositório, clicando em "*Settings*":

[image]

> Em seguida, procure a seção "*Danger zone*", no final da página de configurações:

[image]

> Ao clicar no botão "*Make private*" (tornar privado), você possivelmente precisará confirmar a sua senha. Após isso, o seu repositório estará privado.

Answer (score 1):

Guia github e mais informação, relevante sobre a informação e features que perde/ganha de acordo com a visibilidade:
[Configurando a visibilidade do repositório](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-repository-visibility).

1. No GitHub, para a página principal do repositório.
2. Sobre o nome do repositório, clicar em *Configurações*.
3. Sobre a "Zona de Alerta", próximo do *Tornar este repositório privado*, clicar em *Tornar privado*.
4. Ler os avisos sobre tornar um projeto privado.
5. Introduzir o nome do repositório que quer tornar privado, por exemplo, *accountname/reponame*.
6. Clicar em *Compreendo, tornar este repositório privado*.

Answer (score -3):

Tem sim!
Escolha o seu projeto, vá em configurações do seu projeto, no fim da página tem uma opção `Tornar Privado`.